# 302 Redirect for RESTful API

Tags: api, rest

I am setting up a RESTful API server, and we are requiring clients to use HTTPS. Is it best to set this up to completely block port 80 and return a 'not found' for requests to HTTP, or should I redirect all of these requests to HTTPS? Normally I setup my web servers to do this, but my concern is how well clients will handle the 302 Redirect in their RESTful calls. Is there a best practice or recommended way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach here is to respond with status code `403 Forbidden` and to specify in the response body that a secure connection is required.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad that I could help :-)